# Jupyter cluster gets Kernel busy when other notebooks are running

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter cluster in google cloud and it works fine when running 1 single notebook. When open a second notebook, it keeps showing "Kernel Busy" until I "Close and Halt" the first notebook.

can I only use one notebook at time in jupyter (PySpark Kernel)?
can this be some configuration I haven't done when starting the cluster?

Comment: I don't know the answer of how to fix it, or even if it is a Google Cloud issue, but in general you should be able to have multiple notebooks open at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I only use one notebook at time in jupyter (PySpark Kernel)?

Unfortunately yes, only one

> can this be some configuration I haven't done when starting the cluster?

Unfortunately no

So if you insist on using Jupyter, you need to remember to close other notebooks. However, this may not be a big issue if your script uses all resources of the cluster.

I recommend you to try [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) which is more suitable as the notebook env for Spark.

Comment: thanks @ShuaiYuan. Is this just for Jupyter or other envs (like Zeppelin) also have this limitation?

Comment: Zeppelin doesn't have this limit. You can also config how Zeppelin should [share the interpreters](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#interpreter-setting-option)